# Can we back track to which services a SNS topic in attached to

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am having an SNS topic name(Dev-Alert), I have created subscription to the topic and is receiving email, but i need to find out what services are publishing message to that topic. How can we back track it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'breadcrumb' from an Amazon SNS topic pointing back to publishers.

In fact, a message can be published to an SNS topic with just a couple of lines of code from anywhere on the Internet (not just AWS services).

You will need to scan through the services themselves, looking for which ones are publishing to SNS rather than attempting to back-track.